# how to add items into a CSS based text rotator (similar to news ticker)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement a CCS text rotator (not at an angle, but like a rotating through a set of text).

I am using http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/17/rotating-words-with-css-animations/ and have tried a few others.

The problem is I am unable to understand how to add more items to the ticker. When I add another line, it overwrites the first one.. as through the numbers are hard coded. please help.

I have a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/wc6o9x6d/

In the fiddle you can see - when I added the "Hello" in the end - it cycles through and then overwrites the first word "Spice"

css code

```
body{
    background: #fff url(../images/lghtmesh.png) repeat center center;
}
.rw-wrapper{
    width: 80%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 110px auto 0 auto;
    font-family: 'Bree Serif';
    padding: 10px;
}
.rw-sentence{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
.rw-sentence span{
    color: #444;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.rw-words{
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 10px;
}
.rw-words-1 span{
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #6b969d;
    -webkit-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: rotateWord 18s linear infinite 0s;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(2) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 3s; 
    animation-delay: 3s; 
    color: #6b889d;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(3) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s; 
    animation-delay: 6s; 
    color: #6b739d; 
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(4) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 9s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 9s; 
    animation-delay: 9s; 
    color: #7a6b9d;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(5) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s; 
    animation-delay: 12s; 
    color: #8d6b9d;
}
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(6) { 
    -webkit-animation-delay: 15s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 15s; 
    animation-delay: 15s; 
    color: #9b6b9d;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateWord {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    2% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px); }
    5% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);}
    17% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); }
    20% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(30px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes rotateWord {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    2% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(-30px); }
    5% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px);}
    17% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateY(0px); }
    20% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateY(30px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes rotateWord {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    2% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px); transform: translateY(-30px); }
    5% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); transform: translateY(0px);}
    17% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0px); transform: translateY(0px); }
    20% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(30px); transform: translateY(30px); }
    80% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .rw-sentence { font-size: 18px; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
    .rw-sentence { font-size: 9px; }
}
```

The html is simple as

```
<section class="rw-wrapper">
    <h2 class="rw-sentence">
                <span>Real poetry is like</span>
                <br />
                <span>creating beautiful butterflies</span>
                <br />
                <span>with a silent touch of</span>
                <div class="rw-words rw-words-1">
                    <span>spice</span>
                    <span>colors</span>
                    <span>happiness</span>
                    <span>wonder</span>
                    <span>sugar</span>
                    <span>happiness</span>
                      <span>Hello</span>
                </div>
            </h2>
```

any help on how to add more items in the words will help..

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi each word is rotated every 3 seconds, you need to add css for the last span you have added with delay of plus 3 seconds in this case 18s

```
.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(7) { 
-webkit-animation-delay: 18s; 
-ms-animation-delay: 18s; 
animation-delay: 18s; 
color: #9b6b9d;
}
```

and also increase the total rotate time by 3 seconds (ie) 18+3 =  21s

```
.rw-words-1 span{
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
overflow: hidden;
color: #6b969d;
-webkit-animation: rotateWord 21s linear infinite 0s;
-ms-animation: rotateWord 21s linear infinite 0s;
animation: rotateWord 21s linear infinite 0s;
}
```

Here is the link to [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/xrjhy1yx/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks - that does help - but also that is a little crazy that I have to add a section of css to add one item. but that is how the plugin is written.. thanks.